# Different appsettings.json configuration for the same dotnet core program on the same server

Tags: json, testing, .net-core, deployment, appsettings

I have dotnet core program that I would like to install 2 different configurations(development and test) of on the same server but using different appsettings.json files.

One needs to use appsettings.Development.json
The other must use appsettings.Test.json

Normally, appsettings.json are selected by looking up the value of the System variable called, DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT on the server.

Is there anyone who knows a method to deploy the same piece of software on the same server and there use different appsettings.json files?

Answer (score 0):

There is else way to define the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT, in the we.config file.
If both exists (enviroment variable and in the web.config - the one in the web.config win because it more specific)

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <aspNetCore processPath="D:\Dev\Example.exe" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="false" hostingModel="inprocess">
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT" value="443" />
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
        <environmentVariable name="COMPLUS_ForceENC" value="1" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </aspNetCore>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

To change the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environmentVariable  of the web.config while release there are some options, let me know if you want and I will post them.